# Merge two objects by their same value to display information | React, Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

If I have two objects:

1. `keyedCustomers`
2. `item`

Both of those objects contain a value I need because I need to check a condition with the object `item` and then display stuff from `keyedCustomers`.

In `keyedCustomer` I have this: `_id: "5954aa0433979b24e825de77"`.

And in `item` there's this: `customer: "5954aa0433979b24e825de77"`.

As you can see, the values are exactly the same.

I've heard from my friends that I could use Lodash and do something like: `_.keyby(blablabla)`, but I'm not really sure.

All help I can get is much appreciated.

### Update! Need to add some code

So basically here's my condition:

```
if (item.level == 0) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Denna användare har inte accepterat: {need name-value from object keyedCustomer}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

If the value at `item.level` is equal to 0 a div need's to pop up. And the object `item` does not have the key `name`, therefor I need to find a way to merge them.

Comment: maybe you add some code and have a look here, too: [mcve]

Comment: @NinaScholz I have added some stuff!

Answer (score 0):

If `keyedCustomers` is an array of objects `keyedCustomer`, each having a `name` property, then you can use [_.find](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find) to look up the customer name based on a key that is provided by the `customer` property of `item`:

```
if (item.level == 0) {
  let thisCustomer = _.find(keyedCustomers, { '_id': item.customer});
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Denna användare har inte accepterat: {thisCustomer.name}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```